# javascript search and replace prefix zero

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have few numbers like

0011,0101,0123,1234,5245,0052,3265,0047,0124

How replace prefix zero only,

like no number should start with zero ,

exactly like

0011 should be 11 ,
0101 should be 101 ,
0123 should be 123

How to do this ?

Is ther any javascript function there ,

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
parseInt("0011", 10);
```

will return a Number with the value of 11. Note that the second argument is important, otherwise your zero-prefixed numbers would be interpreted as octal.